# Probability of finding nodes in a moving circle

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

This seems to be a simple problem to me, but am not getting right results.

As attached in the figure (not drawn to scale). A circle centered at $X$ (X in Blue) with initial position at time $t=t_0$ moves to next location (X in red) at $t=t_1$ (all within a square of sides $a$).

Some items (called 'nodes' henceforth) are distributed uniformly with density $\lambda$ in the square (not shown in fig.). $X$ has to discover each item within its communication range. Hence every circle has $N = \lambda\pi r^2$ nodes, where $r$ is the radius around $X$. ($X$ is called master).

If $P_{iN} = NP$ (not to be confused by NP-hard etc.) are the nodes that $X$ discover within in communication range at the time $t=i$. Where $P$ is the probability that $X$ discovers a single node.

Then After time $T = t_0+t_1$ what is the probability of finding all discovered nodes.

---

My solution is:
$$P_T = P_{0N} + P_{1N} - P'_{01N'}$$

where $P'_{01}$ is the probability of nodes that might repeat in the shaded area.

I find this shaded area as $A = A_{circle} - A_{Cresent} = \pi r^2 - \frac{\pi r w}{2}$.

I just want to know if my strategy is right. If someone is interested, I can share the formulas for $P$ as well.
So $N' = \lambda \times (\pi r^2 - \frac{\pi r w}{2})$

[image]

Comment: You have to explain more carefully. $P_{iN}$ cannot be a probability, as it may be greater than 1. I guess $P_{iN}$ is the expected number of nodes that can be discovered.
Also saying that each disc has $N=\lambda \pi r^2$ is a huge approximation (specially for low $\lambda$).
Lastly, I guess $P_T$ is once again an expected value.

It would be really helpfull if you pose the problem and then show how you try to solve it. As it is written I find it very confusing.

Comment: Ah right.... I will make this correction. It is not probability. But the number of discovered devices. That was typo on my side in the question. But the rest remain the same.

Comment: By the way. Since $\lambda$ is the density of uniformly distributed nodes (as in PPP). Why do you say $N = \lambda \pi r^2$ is an approximation? as $r$ is constant, so does $\lambda$. Am I missing something?

Comment: well that depends what you mean with uniformly distributed. For instance if that means they are kind of on a grid or something like that. then the circles may touch a couple more or a couple less depending on the position. It you mean that the probability that a given node is some patch of a given area is proportional to the area, then there is a chance that there are some overpopulated patch and some underpopulated. Due to pure chance. It can be seen that it is an approximation because $\lambda\pi r^2$ might not be an integer. I still find a little confusing but...

Comment: I think I understand it now. What you computed is the expected value of nodes found. I think you are idea is correct (not sure how you compute it the area of the crescent). I also find quite confusing what you use time when, as I understand it, is just two moments when you make the measurements.